# Trouble Creating Canvas for Emulator

Tags: lua

I'm trying to display text on a Lua Canvas in the BizHawk emulator but I keep getting the same error at the line of my 'LuaCanvas.drawText' command.

I haven't found any example scripts for Bizhawk that make use of the canvas

```
gui.createcanvas(640, 480);
while true do
    LuaCanvas.drawText(100, 100, message);
    emu.frameadvance();
end
```

The script opens two canvas windows instead of the desired one canvas, and doesn't have the 'message' string that I provided.

Error message reads:
NLua.Exceptions.LuaScriptException: [string "main"]:3: attempt to index global 'LuaCanvas' (a nil value)

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should more look like this.

```
drawSpace = gui.createcanvas(192,160)
drawSpace.drawBox(5,5,50,50)
```

or try

```
local c = gui.createCanvas(60, 60, 300, 200);
c:onPaint = function(params)
  self:clear(1, 0, 0, 1);
  self:moveTo(10, 10);
  self:lineTo(100, 100);
end
```

Nonetheless, there seems to be a lack of documentation.

Comment: Docs says `nluatable gui.createcanvas(int width, int height, [int? x = null], [int? y = null])  Creates a canvas of the given size and, if specified, the given coordinates.`  tasvideos.org/Bizhawk/LuaFunctions.html

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I copied the second example from an older script I found. I bet the API has changed. Anyways, updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but here's a working sample for BizHawk 2.9:

```lua
local canvas = gui.createcanvas(640, 480);
while true do
    canvas.Clear(0); -- fill with transparent
    canvas.DrawText(100, 100, "Hello, world! "..tostring(emu.framecount()));
    canvas.Refresh();
    emu.frameadvance();
end
```